# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: файлы, golang, файловая-система

Проблема в том что я не могу удалить файлы из-за того что они открыты моей же программой.

Суть работы: программа читает все файлы из директории, проверяет есть ли файлы директорией если нет => переходит дальше и получает размер файла, если размер файла = 0 байтам => удаляет файл.

Код:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    dir, err := ioutil.ReadDir("C:\\Files\\")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    for _, count := range dir {
        if !count.IsDir() {
            fi, err := os.Open("C:\\Files\\" + count.Name())
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            defer fi.Close()

            fsize, _ := fi.Stat()
            fmt.Println(fsize.Size())

            if fsize.Size() == 0 {
                err = os.Remove("C:\\Files\\" + count.Name())
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println(err)
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Как я могу закрыть открытые файлы и затем удалить? P.S: `defer fi.Close()` присутствует.

Comment: `defer` работает на уровне функций, а не блоков. Ну и вообще, если вам нужен `os.FileInfo`, почему вы не используете `os.Stat`?

Comment: @Ainar-G то есть эти файлы я никак не закрою? а можно ли как-то создать новый процесс и там выполнить комманду на удаление файлов или что-то на подобии такого, может где-то нужно хукнуть в win api сисколом ... не знаю.. насчет os.Stat не очень вас понял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас уже есть слайс с информацией о файлах. Просто пройдитесь по ним.

```
for _, fi := range dir {
    if fi.IsDir() {
        continue
    }

    if fi.Size() == 0 {
        err = os.Remove(`C:\Files\` + fi.Name())
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }
}
```